# Find any negative values in a given set of dataframes and replace whole column with np.nan

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a large dataframe and I want to search 144 of the columns to check if there are any negative values in them. If there is even one negative value in a column, I want to replace the whole column with np.nan. I then want to use the new version of the dataframe for later analysis.

I've tried a varied of methods but can't seem to find one that works. I think this is almost there but I can't seem to find a solution to what I'm trying to do.

```
clean_data_df.loc[clean_data_df.cols < 0, cols] = np.nan   #cols is a list of the column names I want to check  
null_columns=clean_data_df.columns[clean_data_df.isnull().any(axis=1)]
clean_data_df[null_columns] = np.nan
```

When I run the above code I get the following error: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'cols'

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because if you are using lists, you should use `clean_data_df[cols]`

Comment: I've tried that too and I get a different error: "None of [Index([          ('p', 'r', 'e', 's', 's', 'u', 'r', 'e', '_', '1'),\n                 ('p', 'r', 'e', 's', 's', 'u', 'r', 'e', '_', '2'),\n       [this carries on for all the column names],\n      dtype='object', length=144)] are in the [index]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a loop to iterate over the columns:

```
for i in col:
   if df[i].isna().any():
       df[i] = np.nan
```

Minumum reproducible example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,np.nan], 'b':[np.nan,1,np.nan],'c':[1,2,3]})
for i in df:
    if df[i].isna().any():
        df[i] = np.nan
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    a   b  c
0 NaN NaN  1
1 NaN NaN  2
2 NaN NaN  3
```

Comment: for such usecases , you can also take a look at `loc` i.e : `df.loc[:,df.isna().any()] = np.nan`

Comment: How does the `df.isna().any()` work inside the `loc`? I seem to be getting an `AttributeError:'float' object has no attribute 'loc'`

Comment: Attribute error stating what? `df.loc[:,df.isna().any()]` returns the first 2 columns since they are true, `loc` is smart in understanding a boolean list when passes after the comma i.e for columns , test with `df.loc[:,[True,True,False]]`

Answer (score 1):

Idea is filter only filtered rows by `cols` by [`DataFrame.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lt.html) and [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) and then add all another columns filled by `False` in [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html), last set values by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), here first `:` means all rows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':list('abc'), 'b':[-2,-1,-3],'c':[1,2,3]})

cols = ['b','c']
df.loc[:, df[cols].lt(0).any().reindex(df.columns, fill_value=False)] = np.nan
print(df)
   a   b  c
0  a NaN  1
1  b NaN  2
2  c NaN  3
```

**Detail**:

```
print(df[cols].lt(0).any())
b     True
c    False
dtype: bool

print (df[cols].lt(0).any().reindex(df.columns, fill_value=False))
a    False
b     True
c    False
dtype: bool
```